How to order factor levels
I am having problems with organizing my levels along the x axis. For some reason my weeks are totally out of order even though I am getting the levels correct I believe. I would like to have weeks 1 to 52 along my X axis but after a few hours trying I can't figure it out. Can someone shed a light on this?
winter_fl <- structure(list(IDWeek = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 28, 28, 29, 
30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 35, 36, 36, 37, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
41, 42, 43, 43, 44, 45, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52), race = c("W", 
"W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", 
"W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", 
"W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", 
"W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", 
"W", "W", "W", "W", "W"), z = c("Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Estimated Fish Passage", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", 
"Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL", "Weekly Median FL"), 
    ForkLength_Catch = c(156, 1704, 825, 998, 589, 424, 332, 
    910, 273, 589, 998, 863, 1645, 2769, 739, 112, 1927, 322, 
    3088, 138, 116, 238, 741, 129, 327, 267, 211, 535, 157, 723, 
    154, 2868, 4944, 1025, 4932, 4005, 7979, 8016, 10644, 30035, 
    12230, 11128, 17513, 22107, 32614, 30997, 82256, 27013, 9993, 
    17056, 30856, 32796, 21939, 25576, 5178, 3686, 1983, 1271
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -58L))


a <-  ggplot(data = filter(winter_fl, z == 'Estimated Fish Passage'),aes(x= factor(IDWeek, levels = c(1:52)), y = ForkLength_Catch), fill= z) +   
geom_bar(stat='summary', fun= sum, show.legend=FALSE, fill= 'lightpink2',color='black') + ylab("Median ForkLength (mm)    and     Estimated Fish Passage") + xlab("Week")  + 
scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)  + scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(1,52,1)) +

geom_boxplot(data = filter(winter_fl, z == 'Weekly Median FL'), aes(x= factor(IDWeek, levels = c(1:52)), y = ForkLength_Catch), width=0.5, fill = 'goldenrod', outlier.colour = 'pink') + 
 facet_wrap(race ~ z, ncol = 1, strip.position ="top", scales="free_y")  + theme_bw(base_size = 9)  +  theme(strip.text=element_text(size=7,margin=margin()), strip.background=element_rect(colour="azure",fill="#f0f0f0")) #+ scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(1,52,1)) 

See below screenshot. My week is not organized from 1 to 52.


Use scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) to prevent unused factor levels from being dropped:
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

winter_fl$IDWeek <- factor(winter_fl$IDWeek)

ggplot(
  data = subset(winter_fl, z == "Estimated Fish Passage"),
  aes(x = IDWeek, y = ForkLength_Catch, fill = z)
) +
  geom_bar(
    stat = "summary", fun = sum, show.legend = FALSE,
    fill = "lightpink2", color = "black"
  ) +
  ylab("Median ForkLength (mm)    and     Estimated Fish Passage") +
  xlab("Week") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  geom_boxplot(
    data = subset(winter_fl, z == "Weekly Median FL"),
    aes(x = IDWeek, y = ForkLength_Catch),
    width = 0.5, fill = "goldenrod", outlier.colour = "pink"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(race ~ z,
    ncol = 1,
    strip.position = "top", scales = "free_y"
  ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 9) +
  theme(
    strip.text = element_text(size = 7, margin = margin()),
    strip.background = element_rect(colour = "azure", fill = "#f0f0f0")
  )


